# Unable to click inside of a game window with pyautogui/win32api/pydirectinput

Tags: python, pywin32, pyautogui

I can click on the window, but it doesn't move my character, or interact with anything in game. I've tried moving the mouse around, i've tried doing keyboard inputs, full screen, windowed, etc. I've also tried using screenshots with pyautogui, but no luck. The game i'm trying to use it with was initially released in 2000. Non coding wise i've tried running it as admin, running in windows xp sp 2-3 compatibility mode, disabling desktop composition, etc.

win32api code:

```
import win32api, win32con
import time

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
# click(573, 841)
# time.sleep(1)
# click(289, 342)
# time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(5)
click(319, 399)
x = win32api.GetCursorPos()
print(x)
```

error:

> ```
> win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y)) pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
> ```

pyautogui/pydirect input:

```
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput as p

import time

icon = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('./icon.png', confidence=0.9)
p.click(icon[0], icon[1])
time.sleep(2)
p.press('enter')
```

this code doesn't throw an error, it completes normally without actually clicking in the game window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are running your script as admin, sometimes if you don't Windows will prevent mouse movement.
Also, try doing this:

```
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0
```

You have to give it a little bit of time to click or else Python will do it too quickly and the game won't register it.

Comment: OHH run the SCRIPT as admin. Damnit, that makes sense. I'm over here trying to run the program as admin. That worked! Thank you